# Updating page with new data retrieved form server

Tags: jquery-mobile

I’m using jquery mobile 1.4.5

I have the following pseudocoded version of a multi-page app:

```
[[ page1 ]]
  [[ button to open panel1 ]]
  [[ panel1 ]]
    [[ form ]]
[[ page2 ]]
  [[ data output from database ]]
```

page1 contains a button that when clicked, opens panel1 with a form on it. The form on panel1 uses jquery validate’s validate() function and which then passes the data to the server via an ajax. The server makes the update to the database.

What I’m trying to figure out now is how to get page2 to update itself automatically with the information newly added by the form in panel1 so when the user clicks on page2, they see the data they just added. I know I can set the data-ajax setting to ‘false’ and have the entire app reload itself with the latest data but I’d rather avoid that, if possible. I’d like the client’s side to load only the data needed for display on page2.

I’ve tried different variations on the following bit of code to get this to work but no luck yet:

```
$(“#page2").pagecontainer({defaults: true});
$(“#page2").pagecontainer("load", '/cgi-bin/some_data.pl', {reload: "true"});
```

The browser developer tool is telling me the `some_data.pl` page is getting retrived. Can someone please point me in the right direction for displaying this new data on the page?

Comment: One other imprtant thing. If I just use

`$("#page2").pagecontainer("load", '/cgi-bin/some_data.pl', {reload: "true"});`

I get this js error from jQuery:

`Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on pagecontainer prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'load'`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I simply used a basic jquery load method to accomplish this:

```
$("#page2 .ui-content").load('/cgi-bin/some_data.pl');
```